# calling a method using self results in error

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, parsing, self

I'm writing an App that is parsing Data from an XML-Doc on the web. So when it finishes loading it is supposed to call the Parsing Method as follows.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
[self startParsingData];
```

}

This should work in theory, right? Problem is I'm getting this error:

> Reciever type 'ffwDetailViewController' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'startParsing Data'

I take it, that xCode thinks this method doesn't exist., but it does.

```
-(void)startParsingData{
NSXMLParser *dataParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:recievedData];
dataParser.delegate = self;
[dataParser parse];
```

}

I don't know what to do. I would really appreciate any help.

Switching their Position did the trick. Unfortunately, now the app crashes on pressing the Button. Here's the full code. I hope you can help me.

```
- (IBAction)getMissions:(id)sender {

if (recievedData) {
    recievedData = nil;
}
_einsaetze.text=@"Pasing Data...";

NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://oliverengelhardt.de/ffw_app/test.xml"]]
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

//Start loading Data
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    recievedData = [NSMutableData data];
}else{
    [_einsaetze setText:@"connection failed"];
}
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
[recievedData setLength:0];
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
if (recievedData) {
    [recievedData appendData:data];
}
```

}

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

_einsaetze.text=@"connnection failed";
```

}

```
-(void)startParsingData{
NSXMLParser *dataParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:recievedData];
dataParser.delegate = self;
[dataParser parse];
```

}

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    [self startParsingData];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"element"]) {
    NSString *myData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"myData"]];
    _einsaetze.text = myData;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have that method declared in the header file?

Comment: You should accept Peter M's answer as it solved your problem.  You now have a new problem, so post that as a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `-(void)startParsingData` is not declared in the `@interface` section of the class (either in the .h or in an extension in the .m file) then `-(void)startParsingData` needs to be physically before `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading` in the .m file.

What order are they in your .m file?

Comment: Thanks! Switching their Position did the trick. Unfortunately, now the app crashes on pressing the Button. Here's the full code. I hope you can help me.